# Unable to read remote system event logs

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I am trying to query event logs through WMI Tester but the result is empty

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, Querying user is member of Admin group on Remote server but not member of Event Log Readers group. When I added the user in Event Log Readers group, issue solved

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run the query locally at ptpc88 and check if it is yielding results. And retry with Authentication as **Packet**.

And if possible try providing **FQDN**.